# PHP - Deny access to pages if not logged in

Tags: php

im new to PHP and have just implemented a login script.

There is no register as its an internal site from only a select few people so i pre-defined them passwords in the database.

All is working ok they can log in and out, however there are pages i don't want viewable if you're not logged in.

They way i have gone about this is essentially checking to see if they are logged in and if they are, display the html to the links to be clicked on. However i get an error in the console:

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }*

**My index.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) 
{
    echo "<div class='mainContainer' align='center'>
    <div class='noteSelectionBoxContainer'>
        <div class='custom-font' id='note-header-text'>
            Choose your Note Category... <br />
        </div>
        <div onclick='location.href='general_notes.php';' class='noteSelectionBox hvr-bounce-to-top1' id='selection-box1'>
            <div class='vertical-align-content'>
                <div class='noSelect'>
                    <div class='noteboxText custom-font'>GENERAL NOTES</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div onclick='location.href='template_notes.php';' class='noteSelectionBox hvr-bounce-to-top2' id='selection-box2'>
            <div class='vertical-align-content'>
                <div class='noSelect'>
                    <div class='noteboxText custom-font'>TEMPLATE NOTES</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div onclick='location.href='variable_notes.php';' class='noteSelectionBox hvr-bounce-to-top3' id='selection-box3'>
            <div class='vertical-align-content'>
                <div class='noSelect'>
                    <div class='noteboxText custom-font'>REPLACE VARIABLES</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>";
}
else
{
    echo "<div class='custom-font' style='font-size: 18px;'> Please log in to view the note categories.</div>";
}

?>
```

normally i can click on the div and the onclick kicks in and send me to the location defined.

Why is it saying Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onclick attributes are defined within single quotes. That means if their values contain single quotes, they need to be escaped. Otherwise, they'll be confused as the end of the attribute value.

So you'd need something like this:

```
<div onclick='location.href=\'general_notes.php\';' class='noteSelectionBox hvr-bounce-to-top1' id='selection-box1'>
```

Notice the backslashes added to the single quotes.

Comment: Im still getting an error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 1):

This console errors aren't php problems. It's about JavaScript.

You have inline JavaScript, and it have single quotes inside single quotes, so you need scape with `\`

```
<?php

if (true) 
{
    echo "<div class='mainContainer' align='center'>
    <div class='noteSelectionBoxContainer'>
        <div class='custom-font' id='note-header-text'>
            Choose your Note Category... <br />
        </div>
        <div onclick='location.href=\"general_notes.php\";' class='noteSelectionBox hvr-bounce-to-top1' id='selection-box1'>
            <div class='vertical-align-content'>
                <div class='noSelect'>
                    <div class='noteboxText custom-font'>GENERAL NOTES</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div onclick='location.href=\"template_notes.php\";' class='noteSelectionBox hvr-bounce-to-top2' id='selection-box2'>
            <div class='vertical-align-content'>
                <div class='noSelect'>
                    <div class='noteboxText custom-font'>TEMPLATE NOTES</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div onclick='location.href=\"variable_notes.php\";' class='noteSelectionBox hvr-bounce-to-top3' id='selection-box3'>
            <div class='vertical-align-content'>
                <div class='noSelect'>
                    <div class='noteboxText custom-font'>REPLACE VARIABLES</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>";
}
else
{
    echo "<div class='custom-font' style='font-size: 18px;'> Please log in to view the note categories.</div>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Im still getting an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Try to use double quotes with slash inside onclick instead.. Like that `onclick='location.href=\"general_notes.php\";'`